# Define global vector using eigen library in c++

Tags: c++, pthreads, eigen

I am writing a parallel program using pthreads and eigen library.
My program looks something like this:

```
#include <Eigen/...>
#include <pthread.h>
...

typedef Eigen::SparseMatrix<long double> matrizLD;
matrizLD mat;
typedef Eigen::Matrix<long double, Dynamic, 1> VectorLD;
VectorLD v1;
VectorLD v2;

void *power_method(int rank){
    ...
    int from = from_array[rank]
    int length = length_array[rank]
    v1.segment(from,length) = mat.block(from,0,length,size)*v2; //something like this
}

int main(...){
    size = ...; //an input parameter
    matrizLD mat(size,size) = ...;
    VectorLD v1(size) = ...;
    VectorLD v2(size) = ...;
    ...
    pthread_create(..., power_method, ...);
    ...
}
```

I basically need the vectors and the matrix to be global variables to be able to access them in the function.
The program compiles but when I execute it I get the following error:

> Assertion failed: (startRow >= 0 && blockRows >= 0 && startRow <= xpr.rows() - blockRows && startCol >= 0 && blockCols >= 0 && startCol <= xpr.cols() - blockCols), function Block, file ...

At first I thought I was trying to access an illegal part of the vector but I then changed the "power_method" function for:

```
void *power_method(int rank){
    v1(0); // I can do this from main with no problem
}
```

and I still get the same error.
My guess is that the way that I'm defining the vector and the matrix is incorrect, but I couldn't find anything that says what is the correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two `v1` variables:

```
VectorLD v1; //global

void *power_method(int rank){
    v1.segment(from,length) = mat.block(from,0,length,size)*v2; //something like this
}

int main(...){
    size = ...; //an input parameter
    VectorLD v1(size) = ...; //oops another one
}
```

Your main needs to initialise the global variable. I presume something like

```
int main(...){
    size = ...; //an input parameter
    v1 = VectorLD(size);// global one
}
```